# Java Failed To Validate Certificate Java 8 Update 25

Tags: java

I am trying to access different sites that use Java and every time I get the failed to validate certificate error. I have looked at the security setting for this version and there are only 2 options, high and very high. How do I get around this error? I shouldn't have to add every site I want to use to the exception list. Here is the error

```
java.io.EOFException
at java.io.DataInputStream.readInt(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.provider.JavaKeyStore.engineLoad(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.provider.JavaKeyStore$JKS.engineLoad(Unknown Source)
at java.security.KeyStore.load(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.deploy.security.DeploySigningCertStore$1.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at com.sun.deploy.security.DeploySigningCertStore.loadCertStore(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.deploy.security.DeploySigningCertStore.load(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.deploy.security.DeploySigningCertStore.load(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.deploy.security.ImmutableCertStore.load(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.deploy.security.TrustDecider.ensureBasicStoresLoaded(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.deploy.security.TrustDecider.isAllPermissionGranted(Unknown Source)
at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.isTrustedByTrustDecider(Unknown Source)
at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.getTrustedCodeSources(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.deploy.security.CPCallbackHandler$ParentCallback.strategy(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.deploy.security.CPCallbackHandler$ParentCallback.openClassPathElement(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.deploy.security.DeployURLClassPath$JarLoader.getJarFile(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.deploy.security.DeployURLClassPath$JarLoader.access$800(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.deploy.security.DeployURLClassPath$JarLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at com.sun.deploy.security.DeployURLClassPath$JarLoader.ensureOpen(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.deploy.security.DeployURLClassPath$JarLoader.<init>(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.deploy.security.DeployURLClassPath$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at com.sun.deploy.security.DeployURLClassPath.getLoader(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.deploy.security.DeployURLClassPath.getLoader(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.deploy.security.DeployURLClassPath.getResource(Unknown Source)
at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader$2.run(Unknown Source)
at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader$2.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.findClassHelper(Unknown Source)
at sun.plugin2.applet.Applet2ClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.loadClass0(Unknown Source)
at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.loadClass0(Unknown Source)
at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.loadCode(Unknown Source)
at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2Manager.initAppletAdapter(Unknown Source)
at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2Manager$AppletExecutionRunnable.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: Post your code. What have you tried yet?

Comment: I have not tried to modify any code as I do not know Java at all. Honestly I think Oracle is responsible for this.